Issue with Shopify Node App Deployment on Vercel
"Hello everyone,
I've developed a Shopify Node.js app using the Node app template from the CLI. Now, I'm trying to upload it to Vercel for hosting, but I'm encountering an error.
When I run the Vercel CLI, I receive the following error message in the logs: "Shopify: unknown command." It seems that Vercel CLI is unable to recognize the "shopify" command.
I suspect that I might need to specify the correct folder containing both frontend and backend code, but I'm not sure how to do this with Vercel CLI.
Could someone please guide me on the correct command to run or how to select the "web" folder that contains both frontend and Node.js index.js files when using Vercel CLI?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!"
